# How to get the difference of time by considering some specific value in python

Tags: python

I have a data set as follows,

[image]

I need to create the activation date in descending order and the time difference of each adjacent row values while considering each NICS. So the final output should be follows,

[image]

Here NA represents that there are no any previous activation dates for that NIC. So that I have used following code to get the activation dates to descending order by considering the NICs as follows,

```
df['Activation Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Activation Date'])
df.sort_values(['NICS', 'Activation Date'], ascending=[False, False], inplace=True)
```

Now I need to get the time difference as mentioned above. As a example the time difference for first row(NIC=1689687896) is NA, mean that there is no any previous activation date. But for  second row(NIC=1689687896) the time difference is 1 month and 1 hour. Hope it is clear.
How should I get that time difference by considering each NIC and there activation dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing will be to get the dataframe corresponding to each NICS ID

Then sort the dataframe wrt Activation Date

Then calculate the date difference (here we will get in seconds and then it has to be converted to months and hours as per the image shown above)

Here is a small snippet performing the same

```
uniq_nics_id = pd.unique(df['NICS'])
difference = []
for nics_id in uniq_nics_id:
    temp_df = df[df['NICS']==nics_id]
    # if dataframe is not sorted
    temp_df['Activation Date'] = pd.to_datetime(temp_df['Activation Date'])
    temp_df.sort_values(['Activation Date'], ascending=[False], inplace=True)
    for inx in range(len(temp_df)):
        if inx==0:
            difference.append("N/A")
        else:
            diff = int((temp_df.iloc[inx]['Activation Date'] - temp_df.iloc[inx-1]['Activation Date']).total_seconds())
            month = diff // (3600*30*24)
            month_str = f"{month} months" if month != 1 else f"{month} month"
            month_rem = diff % (3600*30*24)
            hours = month_rem // 3600
            hr_str = f"{hours} hours" if hours != 1 else f"{hours} hour"
            diff_str = month_str + " " + hr_str
            difference.append(diff_str)
df['Difference'] = difference
```

I hope this solution works for you.

Comment: Didn't worked for me, The activation dates are not in descending order after this code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have a pandas' specific way of doing that but you could do it with a for loop:

```
# Create a new column with NaN's
df["Difference"] = pd.NA

# Set starting reference values for NCIS and start date
nics = df["NICS"][0]
start_date = df["Activation Date"][0]

# Loop through the dataframe by rows
for i in range(len(df)):

    # If the NCIS is the same, place the value in "Difference" column
    if df["NICS"][i] == nics:
        df.at[i, "Difference"] = df["Activation Date"][i] - start_date

    # If the NCIS Changed, update the references
    else:
        nics = df["NICS"][i]
        start_date = df["Activation Date"][i]

print(df)
```

Comment: getting key error (76)at here. if df["NICS"][i] == nics

Comment: Check if the strings "NCIS" and "Activation Date" match exactly how you wrote them in your code (case sensitive) and check if somehow your column "NCIS" is shorter than other column in your df (don't know if possible). Replacing `for i in range(len(df)):` with `for i in range(len(df["NICS"])):` should solve the second possibility...